# Why can't my jQuery.Widgets namespace be accessed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets

I've been reading alot about the advantages of using the **[jQuery.Widget Factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory)** for my plugins. One of the capabilities touted is how the jQuery.widget creates a namespeace for your widget.  This is attractive, as I can maintain my current namespacing (naturally) within the jQuery context.

**THE PROBLEM:**
I keep getting "$(".myWidget").namespace.newWay is not a function" error.

**For the following element...**

```
<div class="myWidget"></div>
```

**[THIS EXAMPLES](http://bililite.nfshost.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/) CODE WORKS:**
While nice...this is NOT what I am trying to achieve...as I still want my namespace to be honored.

```
var workingVersion = {
            _init: function () { /* Do Something*/ }
        };
$.widget("ui.workingVersion", workingVersion);

$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.myWidget').workingVersion();
});
```

**HOWEVER, MY CODE FAILS:**

```
var namespace = namespace || { };
;namespace.newWay = (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

     return function (options) {

          var self = this;

          this._create = function () {
               // Do something
          },
          this._init = function() {
               // Do something
          },
          this.publicFunction = function () {
               // Do something
          };
     };
})(jQuery, window, document);

$(document).ready(function () {
     $.widget("ui.namespace.newWay", namespace.newWay); //<-- Namespace does get appended
     $('.myWidget').namespace.newWay({ type: 'testing' }); //<-- But still fails here
});
```

**MY QUESTION IS:**
Why does it fail?

**RELATED READING:**

- **[Understanding jQuery UI widgets: A tutorial](http://bililite.nfshost.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/)**
- **[Tips for Developing jQuery UI 1.8 Widgets](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/)**

Comment: And your question is, "Why does it fail?"?  To answer that question, I need to understand why you decided to take a different approach and what you're trying to gain from this new approach.

Comment: `$('.myWidget').newWay();` would be how you call it. You don't need to use your namespace from the `$()` instance.

Comment: Thanks for replying: (a) Using the namespace IS the goal! (b) Why append the namespace if you cannot access it? (c) The sample articles imply it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer comes a bit late, maybe, but I was struggling with the same thing and had to do some reading.

**$() in General**

The `$()` instance is a no-namespace shortcut list to different functions spread out over different namespaces. You can add more functions to this shortcut list by writing:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() {
    ...
};
```

Which then will be accessed by calling

```
$("...").myFunction();
```

If you add two functions by the same name the latter one will overwrite the first one.

**Widgets**

When you create a widget with a namespace it's created with it's namespace, as you would expect, but to `$()` it's added without it's namespace, as a simplified shortcut to your real widget-with-shortcut. This is done using `$.widget.bridge()`. You can therefore create your own namespaced link to $() by writing like this:

```
$.widget.bridge("namespace_myFunction", $.namespace.myFunction );
```

And then access your widget like this:

```
$("#myDiv").namespace_myFunction();
```

To use a widget directly with it's original namespace you can instead invoke it like this:

```
$.namespace.myWidget(
  {
    option1: "",
    option2: ""
  },
  $("#div")
);
```

Hope this will clarify a little...

Comment: Great explanation to a question I had long forgotten I asked...+1 atop of the check mark!

Comment: Glad you liked the explanation :)